# Чук и Гек — как их звали?

Tags: литература

Все знают повесть А. Гайдара "Чук и Гек". Но вот я никак не могу понять, а как этих детишек звали полностью? Или Чук и Гек — не сокращения от имен, а просто прозвища?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну как же без этого вопроса. Не помню форума, где бы его не было.

Есть на лингве, в "ответах" на мэйле и гугле... Везде, короче.

Насчет Вовчука и Сергея - ничем не лучше и не хуже всех прочих. даже если допустить, что в рукописи ребятишек звали именно так (чему доказательств я не видел).
Не нравится то, что Гек взято от полного имени и переделано в Гек, а Чук - от совершенно неходового уменьшительного Вовчук. А почему не Борчук или Васчук?
Из экзотических назову историю о том, что это окончания фамилий реальных друзей Гайдара (знать бы, каких) и что имена позаимствованы у Марка Твена. Типа Гек - это Геккельберри Фин,а Чук - естественно, Чак, какого выкопали среди второстепенных героев не помню уж какого произведения. Или просто от того же Гека в английском написании - Huck.

Я все же думаю, что тут не стоит копать уж очень глубоко. Имена просто выдуманы. Лично мне они чем-то напомнили стук вагонных колес... Только это если изнутри вагона - кто не знает, стучат они совершенно по-разному, если слушать проходящий поезд - и ехать в нем...

Как вариант: Гек от Геннадий, Чук - ну, скажем, от Анчук...

> Интересно было бы раскопать информацию о прообразах, если таковые имеются. Может, это пролило бы свет на вопрос.

Так Сережа и Володя - "прообразы". Но опять-таки - одна из версий.
Не могу найти убедительный источник, проще пересказать. Соседом Гайдара по подъезду  был некто Иван Ефимофич Серегин, геолог, у которого были сыновья Володя и Сергей. И еще собака Гектор. Откуда Гек. А Чук, типа, команда которую подают ездовым собакам. В переводе на лошадиный  - "Ну!". Ну и еще сорок бочек арестантов.

Отсюда, типа, и пошло. Беда в том, что кроме как воспоминаниями родственников ничем версия не подтверждается.

Comment: Вовчук не слышала. А вот Вовчик у нас очень даже в ходу. Думаю, это одно и то же. С И произносить легче.

Comment: Интересно было бы раскопать информацию о прообразах, если таковые имеются. Может, это пролило бы свет на вопрос.

Comment: Так Сережа и Володя - "прообразы". Но опять-таки - одна из версий.
Не могу найти убедительный источник, проще пересказать. Соседом Гайдара по ленинградскому подъезду (пардон, парадному) был некто Иван Ефимофич Серегин, геолог, у которого были сыновья Володя и Сергей. И еще собака Гектор. Отсюда, типа, и пошло. Беда в том, что кроме как воспоминаниями родственников ничем версия не подтверждается.

Answer (score 4):

Посмотрите здесь: [Чук, Гек, Кибальчиш - что за имена?](http://2009-2012.littleone.ru/archive/index.php/t-3756550.html) Там много всяких версий и домыслов.

Comment: Я тоже туда заглядывала, интересно

Comment: Да, действительно интересно. Спасибо!

В одной теме сразу множество имён сказочных персонажей обсудили. И Мару, о которой я вчера написал, тоже вспомнили. 

А Мура (ещё одно странное имя), там пишут, это Маша. Надо же. Совсем не похоже.

Comment: Мура - это Маша, Мария. Факт. Хотя, конечно, у кого-то из реальных носителей этого ник-нэйма полное имя могло бы быть и другим. Вы о ком конкретно?

Comment: >Вы о ком конкретно?

О Муре из стихов Чуковского. Значит Мария. Понятно, спасибо.

.

Мура туфельку снимала,

В огороде закопала:

- Расти, туфелька моя,

Расти, маленькая!

Уж как туфельку мою

Я водичкою полью,

И вырастет дерево,

Чудесное дерево!


Будут, будут босоножки

К чудо-дереву скакать

И румяные сапожки

С чудо-дерева срывать,

    Приговаривать:

    "Ай да Мурочка,

    Ай да умница!"

Comment: Мура - рано умершая дочь Чуковского Мария.

>Дочь — Мария Корнеевна Чуковская (Мурочка) (1920—1931), героиня детских стихов и рассказов отца.   
(Вики)

Answer (score 3):

Попалось в сети, что в первой редакции героев Гайдара звали Володя и Серёжа Серёгины. В принципе из этих имён вполне могли трансформироваться подобные сокращения. *Владимир-Вова-Вовчук-Чук* и *Сергей-Сергейка-Гейка-Гек*. Гейка (Сергей), кстати, персонаж другого произведения Гайдара "Тимур и его команда". Хотя возможно, это и просто условные имена, без особого смысла.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! И **Чукче-писателю** за вопрос. Плюсую и за то и за то.

С детства удивляли эти имена. Чук,Гек. Гейка в книге "Тимур и его команда". 

.

У Чуковского тоже есть непонятные до сих для меня моменты. :-) Имена в том числе. Вот странноватое имя для девочки -- Мара. *МарА* на Украине -- это призрачное нечто или некто, может быть даже недоброе. По-видимому очень древнее слово.

Comment: Да,  Маруся,  наверное.

Answer (score 1):

И  в  прозвищах,  и  детских  именах  и  даже  в  отдельных  словах,  бытующих  в  очень  узком  кругу  очень  много  случайного.  Стоит  ли  искать  особый  смысл  там,  где  его  нет.

Answer (score 1):

Вполне возможно, что Гек – это Гекльберри или просто Huck от Huckleberry... как и было сказано выше... А Чук от Chuck... т.е. уменьшительное от Charles...

Или, Чук, это прозвище Чуковского, а Гек эти прозвище другого приятеля Гайдара, либо по имени Гектор (армянское имя), либо по фамилии которая начинается буквами "Гек"... Или самого Гайдара (а почему бы и нет?)...

Типа, Чук и Гек, так друзья звали Чуковского и Гайдара...

Comment: Друзья оставили свидетельства?

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не о сегодняшней распространённой марке (насчитал шесть таковых), а о надписи  на борту парохода из отечественного фильма о дореволюционных годах: возможно, что  ГЕК — аббревиатура (речной) компании? Поскольку нет определённости и с другим именем, в котором есть буква К, полагаю, и здесь та же версия уместна.

Comment: Аббревиатуры до революции писались с точками и ер на конце бы не стоял.

Comment: Эх, не даёте пофантазировать. Да, строго говоря, так и было.

Answer (score 0):

Робяты, не ищите смысл и загадку в именах мальчишек. Это может быть что угодно: просто случайные придуманные имена или домашние "погонялы" тех же Вовы и Сережи, которые использовались только в семье ( у меня доча, когда была маленькая, ее в семье звали Моля, потому что она, будучи совсем маленькой, летающую моль называла "моля", и так во многих семьях). Это неважно, откуда и из какого принципа взяты имена, главное, что писатель Гайдар поступил правильно: он выбрал для своих маленьких литературных героев короткие, звучные, необычные, яркие и запоминающиеся имена. Вов и Сереж было много вокруг, а вот Чук и Гек - эксклюзив, они сразу привлекают внимание и запоминаются.

Answer (score -1):

Как по мне, их звали Чарльз и Гекльберри ))))